# Weird behavior while doing C programming in eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, pointers, eclipse-cdt

I have not touched C for long really long time. My first language was C. But then we have been taught C++, Java and C# (in college days). Now mostly my work involve Java and groovy. And suddenly I have to do C again. I am not familiar with how industry uses C as I never was in project doing stuff in C.

I started in eclipse CDT, with MinGW on Windows 10. My new program grew big quickly. And my lack of experience was unrevealed to me. When I run, my program used to crash showing Windows dialog saying "MyProgram.exe has stopped working". Now I had no clue whats going wrong. Compilation was clean with no error, but only one warning. Now since from Java world, I was like warnings are not that fatal. So I simply just ignored it (I thats my lack of C experience). And went on debugging found the cause. Realised that the warning was indeed about the cause. Suffered mental frustation of wasting hours in debugging.

So here is code replicating issue in my original code:

```
1    #include "stdio.h"
2    #include "limits.h"
3    
4    typedef struct TempStruct TempStruct;
5    
6    struct TempStruct
7    {
8        int a;
9        TempStruct *next;
10    };
11    
12    int function1(TempStruct *param)
13    {
14        return param == NULL;
15    }
16    
17    int function2(TempStruct **param)
18    {
19        if(function1(param))
20        {
21            return INT_MIN;
22        }
23        *param = (*param)->next;
24        return 0;
25    }
26    
27    int main()
28    {
29        TempStruct *tempStructObj = NULL;
30        function2(&tempStructObj);
31        printf("Does not reach here!!!");
32        return 0;
33    }
```

My C-noob eyes did not see anything wrong in it. Good that I knew how to do debugging. I got following in debugging:

[image]

In `main()` this is done: `*tempStructObj = NULL`. So, I was expecting `function1()` to return 1, making `function2()` returning from line 21. 
The issue was that `function1()` takes `TempStruct*`. But on line 19, I passed it `**param`. So inside `function1()`, `param` wasnt `NULL`. So it returned `false` (`0` I guess). So `function2()` did not returned from line 21. It executed `(*param)->next` and hence the program crashed.

My questions:

- **Q1.** Shouldn't be such issue be reported as Error's instead of Warnings? Is there any setting which can report such potentially fatal warnings to error?
- **Q2.** Does eclipse logs the reasons of such sudden app crash somewhere? So instead of debugging by stepping through each line, I can simply refer to the report which can possibly specify the line number which caused the crash
- **Q3.** What is industry-standard approach to deal with such mistakes? Of course one will say dont commit the mistake. But I am asking about precautions that are taken to avoid such mistakes or auto detect them. Like above I asked about settings to make eclipse report the issue as fatal one or making crashes to generate report so that stuff can be fixed quickly instead of hours long debuggins. Do you use any better (and possibly involving smaller learning curve) alternative to (eclipse CDT + MinGW + Windows) that will provide more powerful debugging so that I can avoid such errors.
- **Q4.** In point 1 of above diagram, what is that `Error: Multiple errors reported...`. This stuff occurred occasionally, but not always, say once in 5 debugging sessions. What can be the reason behind such ad hoc behavior?
- **Q5.** In point 3 of above diagram, what is that (`0x62ff2c`) value of `param` inside `function1()`? If I keep signature of `function1()` correctly as `int function1(TempStruct **param)` and change inside reference correctly to `*param`, `*param` is correctly `0x0` (i.e. `NULL`):
  [image]

  **Edit**

  1. [This](http://ideone.com/w1YUtL) on Ideone works (with C) & prints "Does not reach here!!!". So dont know how it handled `(*param)->next`.
  2. [This](http://ideone.com/aluxQx) on ideone (with C99 Strict) does gives error (not warning).

Comment: It looks like you're using c, but not c++. Why you added c++ tag?

Comment: ohhh removed `c++` tag.

Comment: took so much effort to debug and then to write a question and a closing request without commenting what wrong I did that makes it worthy to be closed... :\

Comment: just write function2(tempStructObj), for Q1, you need to find compiler flags like -wall which enables highest level of warnings, for Q5, it is pointer to param, which is itself a pointer. **Value** of param is NULL, but it's **adress** is 0x62ff2c.

Comment: You should only ask one clear, on-topic question at a time. See [ask].

Comment: I cant get how question is **off topic**. Its about C programming. If it is on topic then u must mean those questions are **not clear**. But I have very clearly asked them adding them bullet separately. If thats not issue, then u must b against asking **5 questions together**. But how asking questions related to same context is not convenient. It feels completely logical: to establish context & ask queries.
IMH those 5 questions have same context. If you want I will create 5 new questions with same initial explanation and appending each of 5 questions one by one. Will that do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q1. No, they are warnings as they are legit C code. It *could* be possible that you want such code. You can use `-Werror` on gcc to make warnings to errors. Also add some other flags for turning on more warnings like `-Wall -Wpedantic -Wextra -Wshadow -Wconversion -Wno-sign-compare` etc. This'd be a bit closer to what you're probably used to when using Java ;-)

Q2. Atleast on Linux you have coredumps, iirc Windows was minidumps. These can be loaded together with the corresponding executable into a debugger. Then you can access backtraces, values etc.

Q3.

> Like above I asked about settings to make eclipse report the issue as fatal one or making crashes to generate report so that stuff can be fixed quickly instead of hours long debuggins.

Log yourself. Also there can be macros for easing this.

> Do you use any better (and possibly involving smaller learning curve) alternative to (eclipse CDT + MinGW + Windows) that will provide more powerful debugging so that I can avoid such errors.

IDE is pretty irrelevant for C imho. Use Linux with native GCC instead, MinGW is nice but it can be daunting (my experience).
Ofcourse MS VSC++ can also compile C but its just for C++ compatible thus not really specific to one standard.

Q4. Well, multiple errors occured which are listed. If it's difficult to reproduce it might be a problem in your setup, this is exactly the experience I had with MinGW on Windows.

Q5. It's the address -- you have a pointer to a pointer, so the first ("outer") pointer is that address, pointing to another pointer which is `NULL`.
Or more verbosely:
`tempStructObj` is a pointer to `NULL` (ie.  an `int_ptr` which holds the value `0x0`.

To `function2` you pass another `int_ptr` which holds the semi-random value/address of the automatic variable `int_ptr tempStructObj` is stored
Ie. you have such:

Address `&tempStructObj`: `tempStructObj`

in the RAM.
When you then call `function1`, you pass the value of this (not-`NULL`) pointer. Of course the comparison is thus always false.
You'd need to compare
`*param` with `NULL`.

Even more:
If you compile with GCC (on Linux) and use really verbose flags you get:

```
gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wpedantic -Wextra -Wshadow -Wconversion -Wno-sign-compare -o main main.c
main.c: In function ‘function2’:
main.c:19:18: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘function1’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     if(function1(param))
                  ^
main.c:12:5: note: expected ‘TempStruct * {aka struct TempStruct *}’ but argument is of type ‘TempStruct ** {aka struct TempStruct **}’
 int function1(TempStruct *param)
     ^
```

So exactly the problem you had ^^

Also I'd remove the `function1` altogether, it's completely unnecessary and just obfuscates the code. Also I'd use a different name for the `struct` and the `typedef`, appending the latter with a `_t`. Also I'd move it into one shorter piece of code.
On a side note: add a `\n` in the `printf()`-call.

Edited code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

typedef struct TempStruct_s {
    int a;
    struct TempStruct_s *next;
} TempStruct_t;

int function(TempStruct_t **param)
{
    if(!*param) {
        return INT_MIN;
    }
    *param = (*param)->next;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    TempStruct_t *tempStructObj = NULL;
    function(&tempStructObj);
    printf("Does not reach here!!!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you

```
TempStruct *tempStructObj = NULL;
function2(&tempStructObj);
```

you are sending into `function2` the address of your variable `tempStructObj` (0x62ff2c). When doing

```
if(function1(param)){
    return INT_MIN;
}
```

you're sending the same address (0x62ff2c). Therefore, `param == NULL` is `false`.

Q5: if you use the proper signature, as you suggest, then you check the value that `tempStructObj` is pointing at, which is what you want, and everything works.

The error you get about not being able to access memory 0x4 is due to your structure and wrong null checking. `(*param)->next` is expected work on a memory zone with an `int` and another pointer. However, `*param` is pointing at address 0x0, so the int is at address 0x0 and the `next` pointer is at address 0x4, hence the error.